Pandas interpolate on 2 missing values based on different columns and other specific filter function after groupby
After a groupby on a date column I would like to interpolate on 2 specific values based on different columns and also retrieve the value of another for which the sum of two columns is minimum ...
I guess an example might be easier to clarify. Assume the following dataframe:
input_date   val_x1    val_y1    p1    p2    val3
13/06/2024   0.23      0.17      124   350   0.15
13/06/2024   0.245     0.16      178   298   0.16
13/06/2024   0.276     0.15      192   275   0.17
13/06/2024   0.743     0.22      350   134   0.18
13/06/2024   0.76      0.21      296   184   0.17

So based on that dataframe I am looking to get for each unique input_date value, 3 columns:

one column corresponding to the interpolated value from val_y1 based on val_x1 and value 0.25
one column corresponding to the interpolated value from val_y1 based on val_x1 and value 0.75
one column corresponding to val3 for which the value of P1+P2 is minimum.

I am confused on how to proceed here. I tried to use a groupby on input_date and then use .agg with a set of individual functions to provide the desired results but without success
f = {'interp1': interp_25, 'interp2': interp_75, 'min_val3': min_p1_p2}
df.groupby(['input_date']).agg(f)

Edit: based on the dataframe posted above, I am trying to produce the following (for every unique input_date, hence after a groupby):
input_date interp_25 interp_75 val3_minp1p2
13/06/2024 0.158     0.216     0.15

0.158 is the linear interpolation between (0.245, 0.16) and (0.276, 0.15) at 0.25
0.216 is the linear interpolation between (0.743, 0.22) and (0.76, 0.21) at 0.75
for the column val3_minp1p2, I used an intermediary column set to P1+P2
p1_plus_p2 val3
374        0.15
476        0.16
467        0.17
484        0.18
480        0.17

the minimum of that column is on the first row (374) and the corresponding value of column val3 is 0.15 (which is the result I would like to be shown in the resulting dataframe)

Somewhat confused by the goal description. "Interpolating" is the process of estimating the y between two other y's based on a given x and the corresponding x's of the known y's. It doesn't sound like that's what you're trying to do.

that's exactly what I am trying to do:
0.245 -> 0.16
0.276 -> 0.15
what is the corresponding "y" for an x being equal to 0.25
and same logic but for x equal 0.75 with
0.743 -> 0.22
0.76 -> 0.21
(linear interpolation)

Renaming the variables...
val_y1 -> val_x2,
p1 -> x1,
p2 -> x2,
val3 -> input x,
Is this accurate?

I am sorry I don't understand the need to rename the variables here. I am trying to interpolate (val_x1, val_y1) for two values of val_x1 (0.25 and 0.75). In parallel I am looking for val_3 which corresponds to the rows where P1+P2 is minimum

To make sure I understand what you're trying to do.
which colums are your x1, x2, y1, y2, and input x?

I am trying to apply 3 custom functions in a groupby. There are two linear interpolation on the columns val_x1 and val_y1 for theoretical values of val_x1 at 0.25 and 0.75 and another function which returns the value of column val3 for which columns P1 +P2 is minimal

I added an edit to my original post hoping this clarifies what I am trying to do
